# postfix how to assign virtual account to external user on amazon cloud service

Tags: apache, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, postfix-mta

I installed postfix on my ec2 instance, but how external users can use their own account?

I added `user1@mywebsite.com ubuntu` into `/etc/postfix/virtual`

Of course I need to change user "ubuntu" but how? Do I need to go into IAM and create from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with postfix you installed an MTA (Mail Transport Agent), but to deliver mails to  authenticated users you may need an MDA (Mail Delivery Agent) like Dovecot or something.

i think the Dovecot Virtual-Flat-File-Tutorial is a good point to start.
http://wiki2.dovecot.org/HowTo/VirtualUserFlatFilesPostfix

when you looking for a complete step-by-step tutorial for postfix and dovecot try this:
https://workaround.org/ispmail/wheezy

Comment: ok thanks, but what about the security group? Do I need some additional outbound rule?